# css accordion plus and minus icons not transitioning correctly

Tags: css, accordion, bootstrap-accordion

Here is the situation.

I have set up an accordion using pure CSS and bootstrap. The problem that I'm having is that the icons show - at the start, but instead it should be showing a + sign at the start.

Here is the current css code

```
   button.btn.btn-link::before {
      content: '';
      width: 14px;
      height: 2px;
      background: #333;
      position: absolute;
      top: calc(50% - 1px);
      right: 1rem;
      display: block;
      transition: all 0.3s;
   }

   button.btn.btn-link::after {
      content: '';
      width: 2px;
      height: 14px;
      background: #333;
      position: absolute;
      top: calc(50% - 7px);
      right: calc(1rem + 6px);
      display: block;
      transition: all 0.3s;
    }

     button.btn.btn-link[aria-expanded='false']::before {
       transform: rotate(180deg);
     }

     button.btn.btn-link[aria-expanded='true']::after {
        transform: rotate(45deg);
     }

      button.btn.btn-link[aria-expanded='true']::before {
        transform: rotate(180deg);
      }
```

How can I have the plus sign show when the page loads and the minus show only show when I click on my accordion.

Thank you..

Comment: Hey! could you please include your HTML?

Answer (score 0):

I the problem. What the problem was that I had aria-expanded="true" when the page loads, so I set aria-expanded="false" and that resolved the problem.